# Finding log in terms of variables?

Tags: functions

Back here with another question, as I seemed confused as where to start.

Given $\log_b\left(16\right)=t$ and $\log_b\left(12\right)=w$ . Using the properties of logarithms find $\log_b\left(4/9\right)$.

Answer expressed in terms of $t$ and $w$?

Comment: Hint: $16 = 4 \cdot 4$ and $12 = 4 \cdot 3.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\log_b16=t,\ \ \log_b12=w\\4\log_b2=t\\\log_b3+2\log_b2=w\\2w-t=\log_b9\\0.5t=\log_b4\\0.5t-(2w-t)=\log_b4-\log_b9\\1.5t-2w=\log_b\frac{4}{9}$$

Comment: Thank you, just for my own future reference, why does $\log_b12=w$ $==$ $\log_b3+2\log_b2=w$

Comment: $$\log_b(xy)=\log_b x+\log_b y\\\log_b12=\log_b3+\log_b4\\\log_b(x^y)=y\log_b x\\\log_b(2^2)=2\log_b2$$

Comment: Ahhh. Thank you, I was not thinking of that rule. Much appreciated.